# Throttling notifications from child ViewModel to parent ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a child view-model which notifies on a property change:

```
public class ChildViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged {
    private bool isSelected;
    public bool IsSelected {
        get => isSelected;
        set {
            if (isSelected == value) { return; }
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsSelected"));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

and a parent view-model which creates instances of the child view-model, and listens to the property change notification:

```
public class ParentViewModel {
    public readonly List<ChildViewModel> Children = 
        Enumerable.Range(1,5)
            .Select(x => {
                var ret = new ChildViewModel();
                ret.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => {
                    if (e.PropertyName == "IsSelected") {
                        SyncSelection();
                    }
                };
                return ret;
            })

    private void SyncSelection() { /.../ }
}
```

However, I feel something is wrong with this design, because if I bind a WPF Listbox to the `Children` property, and the `IsSelected` of each item container to `ChildViewModel.IsSelected`:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" SelectionMode="Multiple" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected}" />
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

then when the user selects multiple items at once (e.g. using `SHIFT` and extended mode selection), `SyncSelection` will be called multiple times, once for each change of selection. In that case I would only want `SyncSelected` to be called a single time.

**Is there a better design I could use here?**

(For reference, a screenshot of the UI which this is supposed to enable:)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Delay the Event.**

When an event source is firing faster and updating more often than desired, you can slow it down.

In the listener you will need to buffer the event/events you receive and start a timer. Each time an event is received the timer needs to be reset.

This can lead to a problem where the events keep streaming in. Imagine a user desperately trying to get feed back that their mouse movement was noticed. Naturally you don't want the user to buy a replacement mouse. To fix this you will need two timers.

- The first timer has a short delay, and is reset each time an event is received.
- The second timer has a longer delay. If it isn't currently running the next event will set it. If it is running that second timer is left alone.

Whichever timer expires first, the event buffer is swapped for a new one, and both timers are cancelled. The old buffer is then processed.

1. The old event buffer is analysed to suppress duplicate, old, cancelling events.

   - this may cause some new events to be synthesised as either the result of a merge, or to keep something logically consistent.
2. The remaining events are processed in the order they were received.

Answer (score 0):

Set a timer every time event has fired and ran successfully. While timer is active, some flag is set to false and `if` guard checks whether it must do some work or simply return immediately. Change flag back to `isActive == true` when timer is done.